# Why my function is not called in every single iteration?

Tags: python, function, file

**Code:**

why function **save_path()** is called only for once?

```
from random import choice
from os.path import exists
from os import mkdir

number_of_chars = int(input('enter the number of letters in each file: '))
data = input('enter the sequence of letters: ')
number_of_files = int(input('enter the number of files: '))

def save_path(folder_name = input('enter name of folder in Desktop(press ENTER for saving in Desktop itself): ')):
    # if the folder does not exist on the Desktop, this function creates it
    tmp_path = 'C:/Users/MyComputerName/Desktop/%s' % folder_name
    if not exists(tmp_path):
        mkdir(tmp_path)
    return tmp_path

for j in range(1, number_of_files + 1):
    # each time a file is created in the given path
    with open('%s/test%i.txt' % (save_path(), j), 'w') as f:
        current_choice, last_choice = '', ''
        for i in range(1, number_of_chars + 1):
            # consecutive characters cannot be the same
            while current_choice == last_choice:
                current_choice = choice(data)
            last_choice = current_choice
            if i != number_of_chars:
                f.write(current_choice + ' ')
            # if this is the last character, then no need for a space character
            else:
                f.write(current_choice)
        print('%2i done!' % j)
        f.close()
```

**Output:**

> enter the number of letters in each file: 20

> enter the sequence of letters: gh

> enter the number of files: 5

> enter name of folder in Desktop(press ENTER for saving in Desktop itself):

> 1 done!

> 2 done!

> 3 done!

> 4 done!

> 5 done!

**Result:** [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXgGh.png)

Comment: which function exactly is not called every iteration also could You break the code down to [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `save_path()` *was* called multiple times.  However, your `input()` for the folder name executed only once, because it was part of a default parameter value - which only gets evaluated when the function is defined, not on each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a wrong use of default values. In python, a default value to function is *evaluated once* at the construction time, not called each time you call the function.

```
def foo():
  print('yay!')

def bar(f=foo()):
  print('boo!')

bar()
bar()
```

will print

```
yay!
boo!
boo!
```

So your function *is called* in every iteration, just take "input" call out of a default argument and call it explicitely either inside your function or before calling it.